# Does the Black's equation work for immortal wires / interconnections (or only for mortal ones)?

Tags: reliability, semiconductors, vlsi, physical-design

I'm trying to understand whether the [Black's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%27s_equation) is only true for mortal wire / interconnections or it is also applicable to immortal wires (essentially when its \$jL\$ product is less than \$jL_{blech}\$ where \$j\$ and \$L\$ are the current density and the length of the wire, respectively). In other words, does the Black's equation give a correct Mean Time To Failure (MTTF) estimation for the wires which do not suffer from electromigration (e.i. the wires with the \$jL\$ product less than \$jL_{blech}\$)?

Thanks,

Comment: For the Blech condition, refer to the section "wire length" in the following article http://www.synopsys.com/Tools/Verification/CapsuleModule/CustomSim-RA-wp.pdf

Comment: Cross posted at http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/71130/does-the-blacks-equation-work-for-immortal-wires-interconnections-or-only-fo

Comment: For anyone wondering what an "immortal wire" is, a [Synopsys document on Electromigration](http://www.synopsys.com/Tools/Verification/CapsuleModule/CustomSim-RA-wp.pdf) says "...any wire that has a length below this [Blech length] limit will not fail by electromigration."

Comment: If it does not suffer from electromigration, how can it fail?

Comment: I didn't think "mortal" and "immortal" were technical terms but looking around it seems legit.